# Sometimes, lots of requests from adform slowing down site

Tags: page-load-time, gtmetrix

Trying to get this site ([lanogkreditt.com/kredittkort](https://lanogkreditt.com/kredittkort)) to load as fast as possible but sometimes when i check it with GTMetetrix it does a lot of advertisement requests slowing the total load time a lot. It is not every time, which is strange, only sometimes. I only have one AdSense ad on the page besides a couple static banners+links which does not do more than 1 request each. Anyone know what the adform.net requests are and how to remove them? (the bottom 1/3rd of the requests in the screenshot below)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

These files must be loaded...

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans
https://www.lanogkreditt.com/wp-content/themes/lanogkreditt/style.css?ver=4.8.2
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/opensans/v15/cJZKeOuBrn4kERxqtaUH3VtXRa8TVwTICgirnJhmVJw.woff2
```

Before this JS.

```
https://www.lanogkreditt.com/wp-content/themes/lanogkreditt/js/jquery/jquery-3.2.1.min.js
```